# UITableViewCell not updating after selection on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

So I am having a really weird issue.  My code works great on iOS 8 but doesn't on iOS 7 and I can't figure out why.

I have a tableview which has a list of items which when you select an item a checkmark is added to that item and if you select it again the checkmark is removed.  Pretty simple right? :-p  Like I said it works great on iOS 8, but when I run against iOS 7.1 the cell highlights, adds a checkmark, and removes the old title and replaces it with the default of *Title*.  Afterwards, no matter how many times I tap on the cell, it never changes (but the underlying data does change).

Before Selection
[image: Before Selection]

After Selection
[image: After Selection]

If I leave the screen and come back to it, the rows are displayed properly.  I've verified that cellForRowAtIndexPath is being called and the correct values are being added to the cell.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [[parkFinderSingleton.data valueForKey:@"amenities"] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"amenityFilterCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Amenity *currentAmenity;
    NSArray *amenities = [parkFinderSingleton.data valueForKey:@"amenities"];


    if (amenities != nil) {
        currentAmenity = amenities[indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = currentAmenity.amenityTitle;
        NSLog(@"Cell Title %@", cell.textLabel.text);

        if (currentAmenity.amenitySelected) {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"amenityFilterCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Amenity *currentAmenity;
    NSArray *amenities = [parkFinderSingleton.data valueForKey:@"amenities"];

    if (amenities != nil) {
        currentAmenity = amenities[indexPath.row];

        if (currentAmenity.amenitySelected) {
            currentAmenity.amenitySelected = NO;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        } else {
            currentAmenity.amenitySelected = YES;
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        }
    }

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
```

Any thoughts as to what might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` should not be called in `tableView: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. If you want the cell for a specific indexPath, use `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]`.

For:

> ```
> [self.tableView beginUpdates];
> [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
> [self.tableView endUpdates];
> ```

If you just want to deselect a cell, use `[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:animated:]`.